# How to traverse column of dataset in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to change all column schema of a spark Dataset in scala; Sudo code is like this:

```
   val mydataset  =...
    for (col_t <- mydataset.columns) {
        if (col_t.name.startsWith("AA")) col_t.nullable=true; 
        if (col_t.name.startsWith("BB")) col_t.name+="CC"; 
    }
```

And it is supposed to update column name and nullable property of each (or all) depending on a criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.schema` to get the current schema of the dataframe, map over it, apply your conditions and apply it back on top of your original dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val newSchema = df.schema.map{ case StructField(name, datatype, nullable, metadata) =>
    if (name.startsWith("AA") ) StructField(name, datatype, true, metadata)
    if (name.startsWith("BB") ) StructField(name+"CC" , datatype, true, metadata)
    // more conditions here
}
```

This will return a `List[StructField]`

To apply it on your original Dataframe(`df`):

```
val newDf = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, StructType(newSchema) )
```

Comment: Neat solution.  I suppose the separate `if () => ...` clauses are a single nested `if/else` clause less the `=>`s?

Comment: Thanks for the observation. Yes they are the usual if-else constructs. I'll edit it right away.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the df.schema to achieve this for sure.

The pseudo code is as follows.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ StructField, StructType }
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ DataFrame, SQLContext }

val newSchema = StructType(df.schema.map {
      case StructField(c, t, _, m) if c.equals(cn) && cn.startsWith("AA") => StructField(c, t, nullable = true, m)
      case StructField(c, t, _, m) if c.equals(cn) && cn.startsWith("BB") => StructField(c + "CC", t, nullable = nullable, m)
      case y: StructField => y
    })
val newDf = df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, newSchema)
```

Hope, this helps.